# RPi: Create a RPi server which can be accessed from another device

Tags: android, c, raspberry-pi

I am trying to do the following:

```
(1) Connect RPi to a network (home router);
(2) Make RPi as a server;
(3) Create an Android application which can connect to RPi;
(4) Connect Android application which uses Mobile Data to RPi from anywhere in the world.
```

Can anyone guide me in brute how to do this?
What should I do with client/server applications to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way to acheive your goal way is the following:

1. Connect your RPi to your router like any other standard device.
2. If you want to reach your RPi from the Internet you gonna need to do some [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router,+.
3. On the RPi install a web server like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/) and to store some data you gonna need a database.
   3.1. Maybe checkout [Python Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) it can facilitate the development of the API.
4. Finally you need to develop the App.

Before you start developing consider all the possible solutions maybe a cloud web service could help you and save some time.

Also check [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) which is a lightweight protocol designed for IoT devices and could also help if you need to send commands or other data from the App to the RPi  and vice versa. [Link.](https://android.jlelse.eu/about-the-mqtt-protocol-for-iot-on-android-efb4973577b)

This are few suggestions since you didn't specify what is your idea.

Comment: A cloud web service might be more convenient, but you don't need it for this, and it will cost extra.

Comment: I agree, but you have to consider each option, it all depends on what the OP wants to implement.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now. I was only familiar with LAN network so I was thinking with that logic. Thank you for the suggestions. They actually help and point in the right direction. :)